# How to get specific element out of many elements in data template in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

my listbox:

```
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="26" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSubGenre.PhotoCollection}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="BurlyWood" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Margin="0,0,12,24">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path}" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Margin="12,12,12,12"/>
                                        <Button Foreground="yellow" Click="Button_Click" Height="150" Width="150" Content="add"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>    
                         </StackPanel>
                            </Border>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
        </ListBox>
```

When the button is clicked I want to do something with the neighboring image of the button, how can I specify this particular image in my code? How can I get the neighboring image based on different buttons clicks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the button click callback, do the following:

```
var btn = sender as Button;
var dc = btn.DataContext as YourDataObject;
dc.Path = "/path/to/new/image.jpg";
```

You might have to use a value converter to change the path from a string into a `BitmapImage`.